# In Jo Nesbø's The Snowman, how did Gert Rafto get captured?

Tags: scandinavian-languages, jo-nesbo

One thing that I never figured out after reading Jo Nesbo's The Snowman is how did Gert Rafto get captured by the killer.

I know that

1. Gert Rafto confronted the killer alone, and he knows the identity of the killer. He had his hand on his gun.
2. Then somehow he was transported to his home on Finnøy where he was tortured and mutilated and

   > "made into a snowman".
3. In the book it also mentioned that he committed suicide, but did so by sucking the air out of the gun first.

I am confused as to how this all happened. I believe that Gert was not on the island at the time of the meeting with the killer but was transported there. But I have no idea how the killer got the upper hand.